# Calculating numbers of moles at equilibrium given the volume of mixture and initial concentration of reactants

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equilibrium

> The equilibrium between three substances, A, B and C Is shown below.
> $$\ce{A(g) + B(g) <=> C(g)}$$
> Initially there were $\pu{0.1 mol}$ of A and $\pu{0.2 mol}$ of B in the reaction mixture. A and B reacted together to produce an equilibrium mixture containing $\pu{0.04 mol}$ of C. The total volume of the mixture was $\pu{2.00 dm3}$. Calculate the number of moles of A and B at equilibrium.

I honestly don't know how the answers are $\pu{0.08 mol}$ and $\pu{0.18 mol}$. I got the answers to be $\pu{0.06 mol}$ and $\pu{0.16 mol}$ by subtracting $\pu{0.04 mol}$ from each of $\pu{0.1 mol}$ and $\pu{0.2 mol}$.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Always consider the option there is an error in the task description or the key results.

Comment: Does that mean that 0.06 and 0.16 are correct?

Comment: Do you really need to ask for verification of trivial subtractions ? If anybody tells you 0.1-0.04=0.08, you must know they are wrong. They have probably erroneously omitted coefficient 2 in the equation.

Comment: OK I thought the method I used was wrong. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If given answers are correct, as Poutnik pointed out, your equation should be : $$\ce{A (g) + B (g) <=> 2C (g) }$$.

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at that conclusion ?

Comment: I upvoted the question because it is surely a question that can only be answered (as it has been, in the comments) by someone who has a good grasp of the meaning and the wording of the question and the given answer, and how the answer or the question can be misleading or just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a discussion that took place in the comments:

> If given answers are correct, as Poutnik pointed out, your equation should be :
> $$\require{cancel}\ce{A(g) + B(g)<=>2 C(g)}$$ - Mathew Mahindratne
>
> Could you explain how you arrived at that conclusion? - Ollie

---

This answer solves this question for a general case:

$$\ce{a A(g) + b B(g) <=> c C(g)}$$

Let's assume that initial concentrations of A, B, C are $[A_0]$, $[B_0]$ and $[C_0]$ and the final concentration be $[A]$, $[B]$ and $[C]$.

Now, the given variables are $[A_0]$, $[B_0]$, $[C_0]$ and $[C]$, assuming similar data to the question. Let $\mu$ be change for every mole of C

\begin{align}
\therefore\ &\text{Change}=[C]-[C_0] \tag{1}\\
\implies &\text{Change/mol of C} = \frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c}\tag{2}
\end{align}

Now, building a RICE table we get:

\begin{array}{lc} \hline
 &\ce{a A &+ &b B &<=> &c C} \\ \hline
I & [A_0] && [B_0] && [C_0] \\
C & -a\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} && -b\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} && +c\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} \\
E & [A_0] - a\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} && [B_0] - b\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} && [C_0] + [C]-[C_0] \\ \hline
\end{array}

Therefore, the final concentrations of A and B would be:

\begin{align}
[A] &= [A_0] - a\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} \\
[B] &= [B_0] - b\cdot\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c} 
\end{align}

---

Now, onto the specific solution, how to figure out $a$,$b$ and $c$ given the above convoluted generalisation?

**Point 1**: The change in $[A]$ and $[B]$ are both equal. Looking at change in the above RICE table, we deduce:

\begin{align}
a\cdot\cancel{\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c}}&=b\cdot\cancel{\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c}} \\
\implies a&=b
\end{align}

**Point 2**: We notice that for the change of $\pu{0.04 mol}$ of C, we observe a change of $\pu{0.02 mol}$ in A (or B, both work). Similar to point one, we equate the equations of change of A and C.

\begin{align}
2a\cdot\cancel{\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c}}&=c\cdot\cancel{\frac{[C]-[C_0]}{c}} \\
\implies 2a&=c
\end{align}

Now, we substitute the values of $a$,$b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$, we get:

$$\ce{\cancel{a} A + \cancel{a} B <=> 2\cancel{a} C}$$

which implies:

$$\ce{A + B <=> 2C}$$

Therefore, your textbook is clearly in the wrong, since it states $\ce{A + B<=>C}$.

Comment: It seems to me to be overly complicated. It could be described in just few lines.

Comment: @Poutnik I know.. You can just drop the entire change in C part and talk about ratios instead of actual values. I have no idea why I made it so complicated. I was sleepy at the time.. Also, I want to make sure that there would be no more doubts on OPs side..